# Binding issue with MomentJS and Aurelia

Tags: typescript, momentjs, aurelia

I am building a custom datepicker with Aurelia and MomentJS. I use a property `firstOfMonth` (momentJS object) in my view-model that represents the first day of the month currently displayed. The month displayed can be changed with the following method :

```
changeMonth(diff : number) {
    this.firstOfMonth.add(diff, 'months')

    //...
}
```

The current month should then be displayed in view using a value converter.

**View:**

```
<div class="datepicker-month">
    ${firstOfMonth | fullMonth}
</div>
```

**Value converter:**

```
export class FullMonthValueConverter {
    toView(date : moment.Moment) {
        return date.format('MMMM');
    }
}
```

The problem is, the month doesn't seem to be updated when `firstOfMonth` changes. What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: If `firstOfMonth` is an object and you change something within it, Aurelia can't observe it out of the box. You need to observe it "manually". Simply google for it, there are lot of tutorials (aurelia observing objects). E.g. https://www.danyow.net/aurelia-property-observation/

Comment: I ended up defining a string property for the month to display. The property is simply updated in `changeMonth` method. This solution is quite simple and works well for this case. I read the article and found other useful informations that I will use for other cases, so thank you ;)